# QML File Dialog multiple presentations

Tags: qtquick2, qt-quick

When using **FileDialog** from my app, I get this:

[image]

I initially thought it was the QML way of doing things but it turns out that I have played with example photosurface (provided with QtCreator) and the same **FileDialog** outputs:

[image]

I do not understand where the difference between the two calls come from, i.e. how can I decide to call the 1st version or the 2nd one (I guess the 1st one is best for mobile and the last one better for desktop).

I have played with the import versions:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.2
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2
```

in my case, versus:

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.1
import Qt.labs.folderlistmodel 1.0
```

in the case of photosurface. I have tried photosurface's parameters and obviously they does not solve my riddle.

I have also tried removing my **qtquickcontrols2.conf** (just in case) but that was not it either...

Any idea where the option is to choose between the 1st and the 2nd version of FileDialog?

Thanks,

Antoine.

Comment: One must be using `QApplication`, which enables `QFileDialog` from widgets, whereas the other is using `QGuiApplication` and therefore uses a QML-based fallback implementation.

Comment: Haha, that could well be it!